# Java : Implementing iterator for user-created HashSet class. Semantics of next() and hasNext()?

Tags: java, iterator, hashset

taking a java class and we have to design our own HashSet class. (not using the JAVA apis)

I have to implement and iterator for this, and I am confused about the semantics of using one.

Not sure if a call should be allowed to be made to Next() which will move the index of the iterator, or if a user must absolutely use next() in conjunction with a hasNext() loop which will move the index.

For instance, what would happen if the user had several consecutives calls to next() without hasNext() ?

Thanks for everyone's help!

```
public class HashWordSet implements WordSet {

private int size;
private Node[] buckets = new Node[8];
//above is only provided for mention of variables

    private class Node {
    Word value;
    Node next = null;

    public Node(Word word) {value = word;}
    public String toString() {return value.toString();}
}

class WordIterator implements Iterator<Word> {

    private Node next;
    private int index = 0;

    public Word next() {
        Node element = next;
        if (element == null)
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        if ((next = element.next) == null) {
            Node[] temp = buckets;
            while (index < temp.length && (next = temp[index++]) == null)
                  ; 
        }
        return element.value;
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return (next != null);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The Javadoc specifies that if `next` is called and there isn't a next element, you must throw a `NoSuchElementException`.  That said, you *should not* assume that `hasNext` is always called before `next` -- or that `hasNext` is called only once!

The typical way to do this for a hash table is that

1. `hasNext` advances through the hash table *if* it's not already pointing to a valid element.
2. `next` calls `hasNext` as its first step, and after it's done returning the next element, increments to the next position in the hash table (without checking to see if there is an element in that position).

Comment: hi Louis, thanks for the clarification. Do you think you could point me in the right direction with a snippet of code? thanks

Comment: Sure: the Java `HashMap` source.  http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/HashMap.java.html#791

Comment: ok, I modified it based on the link you sent, but it still doesn't work (updated above) @Andrzej Doyle

Comment: The first problem I see is that you don't move the initial position of `next` to a nonempty node, which `HashMap`'s iterator does in its constructor.

Comment: ...Also, I'll point out that just borrowing the `HashMap` code wholesale isn't really the point.  Understanding the code and rewriting it from scratch is really the point.

Answer (score 1):

Just follow the API as shown here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html

If a user calls next() and there are no more elements, you throw a NoSuchElementException.

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely should be able to use an iterator by only calling `next()`, assuming that it's in a valid state for you to do that.  Checking `hasNext()` on each iteration is the idiomatic way to do things, but it is not required and you should not rely on callers doing this.

In fact, `hasNext()` should be idempotent and essentially should not change any state of your iterator at all.  Since it doesn't change the state, by definition it can't make a different whether it was previously called or not.

So basically yes - every time `next()` is called, you should return the "current" element of your iterator, and then advance the "pointer" (for whatever those concepts mean in your implementation).

> What would happen if the user had several consecutives calls to next() without hasNext()?

If there were sufficient elements left to iterate over, he would get successive elements returned with each call to `next()`.  If he thinks he knows better, and calls `next()` after reaching the end of the iterator (i.e. when `hasNext()` would have returned false), then as per the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#next%28%29) you should throw a `NoSuchElementException`.